# Maps is not showing the current location request on ionic

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, maps

in my app the maps is working well, I am using android and I need to turn on the 'Local' manually in the status bar to work. I want to show the request when I enter in the maps. Bellow is my code, I am using cordova geolocation plugin.

```js
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['ionic'])


.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
  var myLatLng;
  var latCS;

  
  function initialize() {

    
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  latCS =    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.465559, -48.378426);
  
    
        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatLng,
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOptions);
  

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Your Pos'
        });
  
   var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latCS,
          map: map,
          title: 'Your Dest'
        });
  

  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();// also, constructor can get "DirectionsRendererOptions" object
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map); // map should be already initialized.

  var request = {
   origin : myLatLng,
   destination : latCS,
   travelMode : google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); 
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
   }
  });
        $scope.map = map;
    });
  } 
  

  ionic.Platform.ready(initialize)
  
});
```

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear to me, but I assume you want to ask the user to enable the GPS, directly from your app.

If so, please have a look at the great [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin). It has useful methods such as [switchToSettings](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#switchtosettings) (Android, iOs) and [switchToLocationSettings](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#switchtolocationsettings) (Android, Windows Phone).

Before calling these methods, you may display a confirm popup to the user asking him *nicely* to enable the Location/GPS (see [$ionicPopup](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/)).

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to star this project on GitHub if you enjoy it. I personally think it's one of the most useful plugin available for Cordova projects :) (no interests in the project, just my humble opinion!)